# How can I access to https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inceptions5h.zip

Tags: tensorflow, google-api, google-cloud-platform

As far as I know,`$ wget https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inceptions5h.zip` should allow me to do so, but I get the following error:

> Resolving storage.googleapis.com (storage.googleapis.com)... 216.58.220.208, 2404:6800:4005:80d::2010
>   Connecting to storage.googleapis.com (storage.googleapis.com)|216.58.220.208|:443... connected.
>   HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
>   2018-05-02 16:05:23 ERROR 403: Forbidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your request doesn't appear to be authenticated.

> [cloudstorage.ForbiddenError](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/errors)
>   This error (403) indicates that the user was not authorized by Google Cloud Storage to make the request.
>
> The various possible causes for this error are listed in the [Google Cloud Storage error](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-status#standardcodes) documentation for 403-Forbidden.
>   A common source of this error is that the bucket permissions (bucket ACL) are not set properly to allow your app access. See [Google Cloud Storage Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) for information on setting up access.

Comment: Hmm... I am a bit confused. Isnt the data open to public? If so, why "authenticate"?

Comment: It may be public but your still going to have to identify yourself i bet.